# Google Calendar API FileNotFoundError:

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-client, oauth2client

I am trying to create events for Google Calendar but am getting a FileNotFoundError for 'client_secret.json'.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
CAL = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

GMT_OFF = '-07:00'      # PDT/MST/GMT-7
EVENT = {
    'summary': 'Dinner with friends',
    'start':  {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T19:00:00%s' % GMT_OFF},
    'end':    {'dateTime': '2015-09-15T22:00:00%s' % GMT_OFF},
    'attendees': [
        {'email': 'friend1@example.com'},
        {'email': 'friend2@example.com'},
    ],
}

e = CAL.events().insert(calendarId='primary',
        sendNotifications=True, body=EVENT).execute()

print('''*** %r event added:
    Start: %s
    End:   %s''' % (e['summary'].encode('utf-8'),
        e['start']['dateTime'], e['end']['dateTime']))
```

Here is the error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py", line 255
>       warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
>   UserWarning: Cannot access storage.json: No such file or directory
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 121, in _loadfile
>       with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secret.json'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/bakat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Diet Buddy/Google_Calendar.py", line 16, in 
>       flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
>     File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 2125, in flow_from_clientsecrets
>       cache=cache)
>     File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
>       return _loadfile(filename)
>     File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 125, in _loadfile
>       exc.strerror, exc.errno)
>   oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - you must go to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python and follow the instructions to download your client_secrets.json.